# Stateful flow materializing final state

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, dataflow

I am trying to implement a akka stream filter flow which collects statistics on the processed data and materializes the resulting stats.

```
class SFilter[A](p: A => Boolean) extends GraphStage[FlowShape[A, A]] {
  val in = Inlet[A]("SFilter.in")
  val out = Outlet[A]("SFilter.out")
  val shape = FlowShape.of(in, out)
  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
      var positive: Long = 0
      var negative: Long = 0
      setHandler(in, new InHandler {
        override def onPush(): Unit = {
          val elem = grab(in)
          if (p(elem)) { 
            push(out, elem)
            positive += 1
          } else { 
            pull(in)
            negative += 1
          }
        }
      })
      setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
        override def onPull(): Unit = {
          pull(in)
        }
      })
    }
}
```

So far so good, but I would my `SFilter[A]` to be of type `Flow[A,A,(Long,Long)]`. How can I materialize `(positive,negative)` at the end of the comnputation ?

Comment: Maybe you are not looking for that answer, but what you seem to do is basically a `fold`. So, without writing your own stage you could just reuse the existing `fold` combinator.

Comment: @jrudolph yes I though about it, but I prefer to use fold with an immutable accumulator. I am comparing this approach with a mutable (but safe) version.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot materialize a `Tuple2[Long, Long]` since those Longs will depend on the running stream itself. You can, however, materialize a `Future[Tuple2[Long, Long]]` which you then complete when the stream completes.

Edit: And you want to name your custom stage differently so you can differentiate between a normal Filter and your SFilter.

Comment: A `Future[Tuple2[Long, Long]]` will also be good. But how ? I also change the name according to your suggestion.

Comment: @paradigmatic read this section in the documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-customize.html#custom-materialized-values

Comment: @Viktor_Klang may thanks, I was able to write a solution thanks to the link

Comment: @paradigmatic awesome. Happy hakking!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Viktor Klang's suggestions, I was able to implement the following solution:

```
class SFilter[A](p: A => Boolean) extends GraphStageWithMaterializedValue[FlowShape[A,A],Future[(Long,Long)]] {
  val in = Inlet[A]("SFilter.in")
  val out = Outlet[A]("SFilter.out")
  val shape = FlowShape.of(in, out)
  override def createLogicAndMaterializedValue(inheritedAttributes: Attributes) = {
    val result = Promise[(Long,Long)]()
    val logic = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
      var positive: Long = 0
      var negative: Long = 0
      setHandler(in, new InHandler {
        override def onPush(): Unit = {
          val elem = grab(in)
          if (p(elem)) { 
            push(out, elem)
            positive += 1
          } else { 
            pull(in)
            negative += 1
          }
        }
        override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = {
          result.success( (positive,negative) )
          completeStage()
        }
      })
      setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
        override def onPull(): Unit = {
          pull(in)
        }
      })
      (logic, result.future)
    }
}
```